# Incomplete validation message when HTTP POST request payload is empty

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, related_name="profiles")
```

and this is the serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    full_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=60, write_only=True)
    phone = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=20, allow_blank=True, required=False, write_only=True)
    designation = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=50, allow_blank=True, required=False, write_only=True)
    roles = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=models.Role.objects.values_list('id', flat=True), write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'full_name', 'phone', 'designation', 'roles')
```

**Problem**

All requests are sent with `Content-Type: application/json`

1. When I POST a request with an empty payload, DRF raises a 400 (with incomplete required fields)

   ```
   {
     "full_name": [
       "required"
     ],
     "email": [
       "required"
     ],
   }
   ```
2. When the POST request body is `{}`, DRF raises 400, with all mandatory fields

   ```
   {
     "full_name": [
       "required"
     ],
     "email": [
       "required"
     ],
     "roles": [
       "required"
     ]
   }
   ```

**Question**

How can I ensure that if the request body is blank, DRF raises a `ParseError`?

**Already tried**

1. Adding `allow_blank` and `required` to roles in UserSerializer has no effect.
2. There is no inconsistency when I test it using `APITestCase`. I can reproduce the error through [ARC](https://advancedrestclient.com/).

**Workaround**

Added a custom exception handler that checks for this:

```
request = context['request']
if request.content_type == 'application/json' and type(request.data) != dict:
    return response.Response(
        {'detail': 'Invalid body'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When request body is blank, request.data is `django.http.QueryDict`. This is what I am checking against. However, I would prefer to raise this error at its origin, rather than check for a side-effect it creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be possible with normal DRF features.  The `request._parse()` method doesn't call **any parser** if the response body was empty, it just returns a default `{}`.

This means you can't swap out the parser and get your desired behavior on certain endpoints.

```
# request.py @ 301
if stream is None or media_type is None:
    if media_type and not is_form_media_type(media_type):
        empty_data = QueryDict('', encoding=self._request._encoding)
    else:
        empty_data = {}
    empty_files = MultiValueDict()
    return (empty_data, empty_files)

parser = self.negotiator.select_parser(self, self.parser
```

**Caveat**

The behavior you want is somewhat unusual; I think DRF is handling things correctly now but I can see why you'd want a different behavior.  Maybe this is something for a feature request in the DRF gihub?  "Add an `allow_empty_body` flag when parsing (default True).

Note: Empty request bodies are *legal* in post requests.  For example, you can use them to trigger an action on an object such as `post /api/accounts/592/disable/`

There are a few options if you want to go through with this, but they are all awkward and probably broken in some way.

**#1 django middleware**

You could write a middleware class for django to check the incoming requests for `post` and empty body, and manually return the error.

**#2 monkeypatch the request class**

The you could overwrite the `_parse()` method on the the DRF request class with yours at app startup time.

**Others**

It might be possible to do some crazy stuff in your serializer, or manually check in the `post(self, request, **kwargs)` method for an empty request, but they are all a bit hacky.

Comment: I forgot to reply, my bad. I need to ensure that if the request payload is empty, either `1)` Django raises a ValidationError (which might not be the correct action) or `2)` Django returns the correct (and complete) validation errors.

You have pointed out that empty request is not *illegal*. Therefore, how else do you think I can fix `2)`?

Comment: Start debugging whats going on with that MultipleChoice field.  Set it to `required=True`?  etc.  I'm not sure why it might not always return the full validation errors.  If you can replicate the issue with a simple `Serializer` (not ModelSerializer) and a view, that would be best.  Then if you can't figure it out, maybe someone else can.  And yes, stay with trying to get the full and correct errors out.

Comment: Did you ever manage to reproduce the "incomplete required fields" issue?  I remember seeing that a few times, or thinking I did, but now that i'm looking for it explicitly I can't reproduce it either.

Comment: You can use information in my question to reproduce this error, on a new django project with DRF. You just need to

Comment: @Ajoy.  Nevermind then, not making a new DB to test it.  Good luck.